# Where is the smaller menu icon for material design?

Tags: android, material-design

I found [image] but I need[image]

I cant find it here https://design.google.com/icons/#ic_menu.

Where can I find this icon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is this --> https://design.google.com/icons/#ic_more_vert

The image that you have shown is now deprecated and was used in older versions of android.

Comment: This would work as an SVG, I am curious as to whether there is a unicode character that is similar though...

Comment: I will see, am not sure but my guess is no.. simply use as drawable in android.

Comment: It's a vertical ellipsis, I posted it in a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found it! Vertical ellipsis is the character you're looking for!

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/22ee/index.htm

This should get you what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks but I prefer the answer of @Sayan98.

Comment: That's fair. I just thought you might want to see an option that was an actual unicode character as opposed to a graphic.